# Why do my tps drop if a player joins my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Every time someone joins my Minecraft Server the tps drop to 14-16 tps instead of 20 and I don't know why.
Anyone an idea why that is? A plugin?
I use paper 1.16.1 v.6 and I only have Open Inventory, Armored Elytra and Redye as plugins but I use datapacks.
I run the server on a raspberrypi 4gb model B with 2524mb of ram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Raspberry Pi Minecraft V1.12 Server – Excellent Performance Guide](https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-dedicated-minecraft-v1-12-server-excellent-performance-guide/) blog, even a Raspberry Pi 4 is not very well suited as a Minecraft Server.

> #### Should you try this?
>
> Let me answer a big question right off the bat. Should you buy a Raspberry Pi just to run it as a Minecraft server? Absolutely not. If you just want to run a Minecraft server, especially one with more than a few people, you are much better off buying a realms subscription or one of the many dedicated Minecraft server options.

A few paragraphs later, the author describes their own setup, which includes a Raspberry Pi 4.

One of the reasons appears to be storage speeds:

> Second question: Do you have fast Raspberry Pi storage? Because this tutorial will overclock your SD port from 50hz to 100hz. (Update: Since I wrote this article solid state storage has gone down so much in price that it makes much more sense!) If you have a good SanDisk A1 Class 10 card you should have no problems. However, although the risk is minimal, **there is some risk of SD card corruption if you don’t have a high quality card.** I am not responsible if your card dies, your Pi explodes, your house gets hit by a meteorite, or anything else that happens! This is solely at your own risk! These are very common overclocks though and the risk is minimal, but you have been warned!

#### What you can do to fix this

If using a dedicated server (or even a PC) is out of the question, you could try and follow the performance guide linked above. For Minecraft Server 1.14 or newer, you can try [this newer guide](https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-minecraft-server-script-with-startup-service/) instead.

Comment: TY for the info i appreciate you